# Does no output from euca-describe-images mean I'm not connected to the Eucalyptus cloud?

Tags: cloud, eucalyptus

I am trying to setup a Eucalyptus cloud. While using the euca-describe-images, I do not get any output. Does this mean it is not connected to the Eucalyptus cloud or am I doing something wrong ? The eucarc does display the exports.

Comment: Can you run the following command: euca-describe-images --debug This will give us more insight as to what issues there may be.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 things to try.

1. Update the clock: `ntpdate -u ntp.yourserver.br`
2. Restart the nodes: `/etc/init.d/eucalyptus-nc restart`
3. Register again the cluster:
   `# euca_conf --deregister-cluster cluster01 cc-192.168.188.6`
   `# euca_conf --deregister-sc cluster01 sc-192.168.188.6`
   `# euca_conf --deregister-nodes “192.168.188.7”`
   `# euca_conf --register-cluster --partition cluster01 --host 192.168.188.6 \

    --component cc-192.168.188.6`
   `# euca_conf --register-sc --partition cluster01 --host 192.168.188.6 \

     --component sc-192.168.188.6`
   `# euca_conf --register-nodes "192.168.188.7"`